# Open a new tab in react and send query params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

Lets assume I have a button in jsx and I want to open a new tab on click lets say example.com&name=n1&age=n2. I have an object obj {name: n1, age: n2}. I am currently taking out object props and converting them to string (&name=n1&age=n2) and then calling window.open('example.com&name=n1&age=n2'). I want to know is there a way i can just call somefunc('example.com', obj) which will do the same

Comment: I kind of get the idea of what you are explained. Suggestion give more detail and share a image of you component so it will be more information to help you

Comment: Lets assume we have a button in jsx and I want to open a new tab on click lets say example.com&name=n1&age=n2. I have an object obj {name: n1, age: n2}. I am currently taking out object props and converting them to string (&name=n1&age=n2) and then calling window.open('http://example.com&name=n1&age=n2'). I want to know is there a way i can just call somefunc('example.com', obj) which will do the same. I don't have a snapshot with me as of now

Answer (score 0):

Try with new feature of React 16 -
[portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

You can also check [this](https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) great article from Hackernoon about this. At the end you'll find David Gilbertson live code example.
It could be what are you looking for.